# Getting a return of [] when using BS4 on a webpage

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to return data from a website using bs4. I'm not sure if I'm targeting the right classes or using bs4 the wrong way to get the table of information I want.

I've tried using different methods but I can't find the right documentation for the info I want to scrape from the website

````
>>> ```import bs4
>>> import requests
>>> res = requests.get('https://www.5dimes.eu/livelines/livelines.aspx')
>>> type(res)
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)
>>> type(soup)
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
>>> soup.title
<title>
    Live Lines
</title>
>>> soup.select('.LR Alt')
[]
>>> soup.select('.LSR')
[]
>>> soup.select('h2 > span')
[]
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
>>> type(soup)
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
>>> soup.select('.LR Alt')
[]
>>> 
```
````

I want to get at least an array of team names or odds but instead I just get the [] result

Comment: www.5dimes.eu - Access Denied  - GDPR?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
from re import sub
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
urlpage=urlopen("https://www.5dimes.eu/livelines/livelines.aspx").read()
bswebpage=BeautifulSoup(urlpage)
results=bswebpage.findAll("div",{'class':'SportSubTypes'})
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

[image]

Result:

```
<span class="Group SportSubType">
<input id="c_23" type="checkbox"/> <a href="#ac_23" rs:checkbox="c_23" title="Scroll to the latest lines for this sport.">Rugby Union Futures</a>
</span>
<span class="Group SportSubType">
<input id="c_24" type="checkbox"/> <a href="#ac_24" rs:checkbox="c_24" title="Scroll to the latest lines for this sport.">Snooker Futures</a>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Wasn’t exactly what I was looking for but the find.all function in your code helped me get to the answer :)

Comment: Please click 'this answer is useful'.  Thanks.